Why are all instances of my Class being modified when only a single object's attributes should be changed?
I have 2 objects (1 & 2) from a class and 1 object (A) from another class. When I am using a function from A in order to change attributes of object 1, object 2's attributes are being changed and I have no idea why.
import numpy as np

allflows = []
processunits = []

class Flow:
    def __init__(self, name = '', components = '', flow_type = '',
                 temperature=25, pressure = 1, composition = [1], origin = None, 
                 destination = None, mass_flow_rate = 0, elec_flow_rate = 0, 
                 heat_flow_rate = 0, is_calc_flow = False):
        self.attributes = {'name' : name, 'components' : components, 'flow_type' :
                           flow_type, 'temperature' : temperature, 'pressure':
                           pressure, 'composition' : composition, 'origin' :
                           origin, 'destination' : destination, 'mass_flow_rate':
                           mass_flow_rate, 'elec_flow_rate' : elec_flow_rate,
                           'heat_flow_rate': heat_flow_rate}
        self.is_calc_flow = is_calc_flow
        
    def set_destination(self, Destination_unit):
        if self.attributes['destination'] == Destination_unit.name and self.attributes['name'] in Destination_unit.input_flows:
            pass  # Do nothing if already correctly assigned
        elif self.attributes['destination'] != Destination_unit.name:
            if self.attributes['destination']:  # Remove from previous destination if exists
                prev_unit = next((unit for unit in processunits if unit.name == self.attributes['destination']), None)
                if prev_unit:
                    prev_unit.input_flows.remove(self.attributes['name'])
            # Add to new destination
            Destination_unit.input_flows.append(self.attributes['name'])
            self.attributes['destination'] = Destination_unit.name
        print(f"Flow {self.attributes['name']} set destination to {self.attributes['destination']}")


class Unit:
    def __init__(self, name, input_flows = [], output_flows = [], 
                 calculations = {}, expected_flows_in = [], expected_flows_out = [], coefficients = [], is_calc = False):
        self.name = name
        self.input_flows = input_flows
        self.output_flows = output_flows
        self.calculations = calculations
        self.expected_flows_in = expected_flows_in
        self.expected_flows_out = expected_flows_out
        self.coefficients = coefficients
        self.is_calc = is_calc

                    
Unit1 = Unit('Unit 1')
Unit2 = Unit('Unit 2')
Unit1.expected_flows_in = ['A']
Unit1.expected_flows_out = ['B', 'D']
Unit1.coefficients = 0.6
def Unit1func(flow, coeff):
    a_amount = flow.attributes['mass_flow_rate']
    b_amount = coeff*a_amount
    d_amount = a_amount - b_amount
    return [{'name' : 'B', 'components' : 'B', 'mass_flow_rate' : b_amount,
             'flow_type': 'Process stream', 'In or out' : 'Out'},
            {'name' : 'D', 'components' : 'D', 'mass_flow_rate' : d_amount,
                     'flow_type': 'Process stream', 'In or out' : 'Out'}]


FlowA = Flow('A', 'A','input', 25, 1, [1], np.nan , np.nan, 1000, np.nan, np.nan)

print(f"Initial input flows of Unit2: {Unit2.input_flows}")
print(f"Initial output flows of Unit2: {Unit2.output_flows}")

FlowA.set_destination(Unit1)

print(f"Input flows of Unit2 after setting FlowA's destination to Unit1: {Unit2.input_flows}")
print(f"Output flows of Unit2 after setting FlowA's destination to Unit1: {Unit2.output_flows}")

print(Unit1)
print(Unit2)


And console output is:
Initial input flows of Unit2: []
Initial output flows of Unit2: []
Flow A set destination to Unit 1
Input flows of Unit2 after setting FlowA's destination to Unit1: ['A']
Output flows of Unit2 after setting FlowA's destination to Unit1: []
<__main__.Unit object at 0x0000022BDCB9CC50>
<__main__.Unit object at 0x0000022BDCB9F500>

Ideally, I would expect only the Unit1 to be modified, while Unit2 would be left untouched by using set_destination. I don't know what causes this issue, since Unit1 & Unit2 don't share the same memory space and a priori set_destination only modifies the unit in argument. Does anyone know what causes this issue? Or know of a better workaround?
Thanks in advance!

The problem is the use of mutable default arguments such as input_flows = [] in the __init__ function of the Unit class.  Because this is part of the method definition, the default assignment input_flows = [] only happens once.  You do not get a fresh empty list on each call.

This is a dupe but yeah, the default is either no default, or default None and then within the function if None make it an empty list
